# Attempting to create a threadguard with move semantics

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

the title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to get a minimal working example of a thread guard that can also support the move semantics that std::threads have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class ThreadGuard {
public:
    explicit ThreadGuard(std::thread input): t(std::move(input))
    {}
    ~ThreadGuard(){
        if(t.joinable()){
            t.join();
        }
    }
    ThreadGuard(ThreadGuard const& t) = delete;
    ThreadGuard& operator=(ThreadGuard const&) = delete;

    ThreadGuard& operator=(ThreadGuard&& out){
        this->t = out.transfer();
        return *this;
    }
    std::thread transfer(){
        return std::move(t);
    }
private:
    std::thread t;
};

void doWork(std::string input){
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
}

static const auto numThreads = 4;
int main()
{
    std::vector<ThreadGuard> tp;
    tp.reserve(numThreads);
    for(auto i = 0 ; i < numThreads; ++i){
        tp[i] = ThreadGuard(std::thread(doWork, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently running into a roadblock. std::invoke, no matching overloaded function found and I fail to see what's missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the `int` to `std::string`:

```
tp[i] = ThreadGuard(std::thread(doWork, std::to_string(i)));
```

You also do not need to write your own move constructor and move assignment operator. Use the `default`:

```
class ThreadGuard {
public:
    explicit ThreadGuard(std::thread&& input): t(std::move(input))
    {}
    ThreadGuard(ThreadGuard const& t) = delete;
    ThreadGuard(ThreadGuard&&) noexcept = default;
    ThreadGuard& operator=(ThreadGuard const&) = delete;
    ThreadGuard& operator=(ThreadGuard&&) noexcept = default;  
    ~ThreadGuard(){
        if(t.joinable()){
            t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread t;
};
```

You could also make the converting constructor accept the thread constructor arguments and forward them directly:

```
    template<typename...Args>
    explicit ThreadGuard(Args&&... args): t(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
```

which would allow it to be created like this:

```
tp[i] = ThreadGuard(doWork, std::to_string(i));
```

Also worth noting: In C++20 [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) was added which `join()`s automatically on destruction.

Comment: `ThreadGuard& operator=(ThreadGuard&&) noexcept = default;` I think is wrong, you should write this yourself. You need to check whether `this->t` is _joinable_ (and join it) before you write over it.

Comment: @MikeVine The default behavior (which is what OP also has) would call `std::terminate` in that case. It may or may not be what OP wants but I just kept the same logic in the answer.

Comment: Yes OP has this bug (?) too. It would be a _very_ strange class which wouldn't clean up for itself in that scenario. Its simple to fix - or if you _really_ want to terminate in that scenario then being explicit seems right.

Comment: @MikeVine It's a matter of taste I'd say. This thin wrapper behaves just as `std::thread` with the exception that it autojoins on destruction. `std::jthread` on the other hand has a smarter move assignment operator that calls `request_stop()` and then `join()`. For something similar to work with `std::thread` one would need to add an atomic that would need to be checked. Just `join()`ing would risk leading to all sorts of troubles.

Comment: 1+ for the complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the input everyone. YesI know about jthread but I need to use c++11 atm. I also didn't know abut the bug @MikeVine pointed out. Thanks.